# CDC JSON Data format for SAP

Tags: mysql, json, connector, change-data-capture, oracle-cdc

As MySQL along with Debezium has this particular CDC JSON data format.

```
{
   "before":null,
   "after": {
      "pk":"1",
      "value":"New data"
   },
   "source": {
      "snapshot":"incremental"
   },
   "op":"r",
   "ts_ms":"1620393591654",
   "transaction":null
}
```

Does every database have different CDC JSON data format? If we change connector, for example instead of debezium any other connector. Will this JSON data format change? Or Just columns and table values are going to change?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This so depends upon what you are using to generate this

Comment: I will be using connectors to fetch out CDC data out of different databases and want to insert into Kafka, So I want to make sure that these formats will be different or same.